# (WP) How to list all post from custom post types?

Tags: php, wordpress, post

How to list all post from custom post types? Such as, post types = videos

I want list all post title + id of post from this post types only. Thanks. :D

Comment: Post relevant code... Can't get with what you have specified

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
<?php
global $post;
$myposts = get_posts('post_type=videos&posts_per_page=-1');
foreach($myposts as $post) : setup_postdata($post);
?>
<h1><?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>, <?php the_title(); ?></h1>
 <?php endforeach; ?>
```

The above should list out the `ids` and the `titles` of all the posts in the `videos` post type.

Comment: Also supply posts_per_page = -1 in the get_posts(), otherwise it only shows the amount of posts that is set in the admin-panel (I think default is 20)